# How can I draw a cross which follows my mouse cursor?

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, pyqt

I want draw a cross in my `paintEvent()` which moves with the mouse. I'm using python via pyqt.

I'm using the code below, but the result isn't good.

```
from __future__ import division
import sys
import platform

# Qt4 bindings for core Qt functionalities (non-GUI)
import PyQt4.QtCore as  QtCore

# Python Qt4 bindings for GUI objects
import PyQt4.QtGui as QtGui
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
# import the Qt4Agg FigureCanvas object, that binds Figure to
# Qt4Agg backend. It also inherits from QWidget
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
# Matplotlib Figure object
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class C_MplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self):      
        # setup Matplotlib Figure and Axis
        self.fig = Figure()
        #self.cursor = Cursor()
        self.fig.set_facecolor('black')
        self.fig.set_edgecolor('black')
        #self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        #self.ax.patch.set_facecolor('black')
        # initialization of the canvas
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)
        #super(FigureCanvas, self).__init__(self.fig)


        # we define the widget as expandable
        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
                                   QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                                   QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        # notify the system of updated policy
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

        self.xx=0
        self.yy=0
        self.justDoubleClicked=False

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        menu = QMenu(self)
        oneAction = menu.addAction("&One")
        twoAction = menu.addAction("&Two")
        self.connect(oneAction, SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.one)
        self.connect(twoAction, SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.two)
        '''
        if not self.message:
            menu.addSeparator()
            threeAction = menu.addAction("Thre&e")
            self.connect(threeAction, SIGNAL("triggered()"),
                         self.three)
        '''
        menu.exec_(event.globalPos())


    def one(self):
        self.message = QString("Menu option One")
        self.update()


    def two(self):
        self.message = QString("Menu option Two")
        self.update()


    def three(self):
        self.message = QString("Menu option Three")
        self.update()


    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.TextAntialiasing)
        #painter.drawText(self.rect(), Qt.AlignCenter, text)
        #

        #painter.setPen('red')

        pen=painter.pen()
        painter.setPen(QColor(255, 0, 0))

        painter.drawLine(self.xx-100,self.yy,self.xx+100,self.yy)
        painter.drawLine(self.xx,self.yy-100,self.xx,self.yy+100)
        self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if self.justDoubleClicked:
            self.justDoubleClicked = False
        else:
            self.setMouseTracking(not self.hasMouseTracking())
            self.update()


    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):      
        self.xx=event.pos().x()
        self.yy=event.pos().y()
        self.update()




class C_MPL(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        # initialization of Qt MainWindow widget
        super(C_MPL, self).__init__(parent)
        #QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        # instantiate a widget, it will be the main one
        #self.main_widget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        #vbl = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.main_widget)
        # set the canvas to the Matplotlib widget
        self.canvas = C_MplCanvas()

        # create a vertical box layout
        self.vbl = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        # add mpl widget to vertical box
        self.vbl.addWidget(self.canvas)
        # set the layout to th vertical box
        self.setLayout(self.vbl)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    '''
    def valueChanged(a, b):
        print a, b
    '''
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = C_MPL()
    #form.connect(form, SIGNAL("valueChanged"), valueChanged)
    form.setWindowTitle("C_MPL")
    #form.move(0, 0)
    form.show()
    #form.resize(400, 400)
    app.exec_()
```

@bmu: That's great,just like I want.And now there another question:

```
    cid0=self.mpl_connect('axes_enter_event', self.enter_axes)
    cid1=self.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.onpick)
    cid2=self.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.onmove)
    cid3=self.mpl_connect('draw_event', self.clear)
    cid4=self.mpl_connect('key_press_event',self.press)
```

the strange thing is the 'key_press_event' can't be triggerd but all other events can. there r a case: macosx backend ignores multiple mpl_connect() calls
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/585, 
but i think it's differnt with me.
i got cid0,1,2,3,4 which is different each other

So , any idea can share? I an very crazy now.....
Following is my code,u can test it if u have the same problem:

```
import sys
import platform

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4 import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
import time
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *




#Just a test 

class MplCanvas(FigureCanvas):

    def __init__(self):

        # initialization of the canvas
        self.fig=Figure()
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self,self.fig )



        self.ax = self.fig.add_axes([.15, .15, .75, .75])
        self.canvas = self.ax.figure.canvas     



        #my added
        #self.ax = self.fig.add_axes([.15, .15, .75, .75])
        #cursor = C_Cursor(self.LvsT, useblit=True, color='red', linewidth=2 )



        x=np.arange(0,20,0.1)

        self.ax.plot(x,x*x,'o')
        self.ax.set_xlim(-2,2)
        self.ax.set_ylim(-2,2) 

        self.visible = True
        self.horizOn = True
        self.vertOn = True
        self.useblit = True

        #if self.useblit:
            #lineprops['animated'] = True


        self.lineh = self.ax.axhline(self.ax.get_ybound()[0], visible=False)
        self.linev = self.ax.axvline(self.ax.get_xbound()[0], visible=False)

        self.background = None
        self.needclear = False

        self.count = 0

        cid0=self.mpl_connect('axes_enter_event', self.enter_axes)
        cid1=self.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.onpick)
        cid2=self.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.onmove)
        cid3=self.mpl_connect('draw_event', self.clear)
        cid4=self.mpl_connect('key_press_event',self.press)

        self.draw()

    def clear(self, event):
        'clear the cursor'
        if self.useblit:
            self.background = self.canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.ax.bbox)
        self.linev.set_visible(False)
        self.lineh.set_visible(False)

    def onmove(self, event):
        'on mouse motion draw the cursor if visible'
        print("move")
        if event.inaxes != self.ax:
            self.linev.set_visible(False)
            self.lineh.set_visible(False)

            if self.needclear:
                self.canvas.draw()
                self.needclear = False
            return
        self.needclear = True
        if not self.visible: return
        self.linev.set_xdata((event.xdata, event.xdata))

        self.lineh.set_ydata((event.ydata, event.ydata))
        self.linev.set_visible(self.visible and self.vertOn)
        self.lineh.set_visible(self.visible and self.horizOn)


        self._update()




    def _update(self):

        if self.useblit:
            if self.background is not None:
                self.canvas.restore_region(self.background)
            self.ax.draw_artist(self.linev)
            self.ax.draw_artist(self.lineh)
            self.canvas.blit(self.ax.bbox)
        else:

            self.canvas.draw_idle()

        return False

        #



    def enter_axes(self,event):

        print "Enter"

    def onpick(self,event):
        print "click"
        print 'you pressed', event.canvas

        a = np.arange(10)
        print a
        print self.count

        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        ax.plot(a)    
        fig.show()

    def press(self,event):
        print ('press', event.key)
        self.fig.canvas.draw()




class MplWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)        

        self.vbl = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.canvas = MplCanvas()
        self.vbl.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.setLayout(self.vbl)




if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MplWidget()
    form.show()
    #form.resize(400, 400)
    app.exec_()
```

@all:Tks all. I resolved this problem after added:

```
self.canvas.setFocusPolicy( Qt.ClickFocus )
self.canvas.setFocus()
```

maybe this a little bug bcs i need explicity setfocus on cavans,maybe if not:)
details u can check https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/707

Comment: do you need qt directly? I think it would be simpler with matplotlib [event handling](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/event_handling.html#event-handling-and-picking), especially the `motion_notify_event`.

Comment: mpl_connect sounds good ,i will try it.

Comment: Hi,sjwarner
Can I use mpl_connect in FigureCanvas from which  matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg ,if so, could u give me a example. I had coded a script,but it didn't work.:(

Comment: hi tianli, I received your comment. If you want to dedicate a comment to user, you should use @username.

Comment: Thanks.@bmu. And I had worked out this.But I am very very puzzle. Now is the 'key_press_event' can not be triggered, but 'motion_notify_event' can. why????? It looks just like a ghost ,I am crazy now, OOPs self.mpl_connect('axes_enter_event', self.enter_axes) self.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.onpick) self.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.onmove) self.mpl_connect('draw_event', self.clear) self.mpl_connect('key_press_event',self.press)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using matplotlib [event handling](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/event_handling.html#event-handling-and-picking) (however I am wondering, if it is really useful to have something like a second cursor).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 


class MouseCross(object):

    def __init__(self, ax, **kwargs):
        self.ax = ax
        self.line, = self.ax.plot([0], [0], visible=False, **kwargs)

    def show_cross(self, event):
        if event.inaxes == self.ax:
            self.line.set_data([event.xdata], [event.ydata])
            self.line.set_visible(True)
        else:
            self.line.set_visible(False)
        plt.draw()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(np.random.random(100) * 10.0)
    # note that not every "normal" matplotlib marker will work
    # math symbols work fine
    cross = MouseCross(ax, marker=r'$\bigoplus$', markersize=30,
                       color='red',)
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', cross.show_cross)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Question...are you trying to change what the cursor looks like over your widget?  If so, the easiest thing is to do get rid of the paintEvent entirely, and add setCursor to your init method:

```
class C_MplCanvas(FigureCanva):
    def __init__( self ):
        # setup code
        ...
        self.setCursor(Qt.CrossCursor)
```

This will tell Qt to use the Cross Cursor whenever the mouse is over that particular widget.  This will actually replace the arrow (which may or may not be what you want).  If that isn't what you want, I would recommend doing something where you create a PNG image of what you do want, create a child QLabel, and move the child widget around in your mouseMoveEvent.

If you need more help on that lemme know.

Comment: Tks.In fact ,I want to implement the funtion as this: cursor = Cursor(ax, useblit=True, color='red', linewidth=2 )